# How Can I install A Rhythmbox Plugin On My Ubuntu VPS?

Tags: command-line, server, software-installation, rhythmbox, vps

I am trying to install a Rhythmbox Plugin (File Organizer https://launchpad.net/rb-fileorganizer) on my VPS Ubuntu installation. On the desktop, I would be required to open the folder then double click Install.

On the server, I downloaded the plugin got to the directory but I have no way or 'double clicking' of running the installation file via the terminal.

I have attached an image of what I see. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the README

```
less ./README
```

type <kbd>q</kbd> to quit less when done.

I assume you will run the installer

```
 ./INSTALL
```

You may need to change the permissions first

```
chmod a+x ./INSTALL
```

Comment: ./INSTALL: line 5: make: command not found

Comment: You are going to have to identify and install any and all dependencies. You might want to start with `apt-get isntall build-essential` - that might fail on your VPS and if so, you will have to install them as needed. `apt-get install make`

Answer (score 1):

I'm the current maintainer of this plugin.

I just extract releases into the plugin directory, the required path path is:

```
$(HOME)/.local/share/rhythmbox/plugins/fileorganizer-gtk3/
```

To install from the commandline type:

```
make install
```

Or:

```
make install-gui
```

The `install` file is just a shortcut for `install-gui`. If it's not executable that's a bug I can look at for you.

Answer (score 0):

People are really helpful on this website. I found a "grass roots" answer for "blunderers" and avid "new-to-Linux" dabblers, like myself. Here is a helpful URL if you need 'absolute beginner' help on command line protocol for this type of file.

[How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file).

I sorted it out without being a further nuisance and maybe URL will help others like myself who prize *Linux Ubuntu*. *Rhythmbox Music Player* is a fine app.

By the way, the *Rhythmbox File Organizer* is a rather nifty plugin.